# How to prep site for patio on uneven ground?

Tags: patio

I'm going to be putting a patio in behind our house and trying to figure out how deep I need to go. I'm going to be covering a 18' area that has a slight dip running the length of it.

[image]

I could go two ways here. I understand I need about 4" of gravel fill, but I'm not sure whether I need to fill "up" or "down".  If I fill down 4" below the lowest point, that will require a bit more than twice the fill, so I need to work this out before placing the order.

**Option 1:** Fill "Up" from the low spot (after removing sod):
[image]

**Option 2:** Fill "Down" from 4" below the lowest point:
[image]

I don't really see any difference between the two choices (except for using more fill) since ultimately the soil is going to be tamped down just the same regardless of wether it is done 4" higher or lower. But I've found people insisting that both are correct online, and would love a tie-breaking decision :D

Comment: *How to prep site for patio on uneven ground?* Prep the ground by     **First making the ground level** at a depth equal to the combined **compacted gravel** and **the material?** that will be used for the patio so patio sits a the correct height you have predetermined.